# Can I control the way SQL Server handles its execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

**Situation:**

I often have (no comments on database, it is history :)) columns where values are separated.

So let's say we have a column `params` which contains for example `1,2,3,4,5`.

If I need the values table based I split them with a `dbo.fn_Split()` function (several version can be found on the net - but out of scope here). So I get my virtual table.

Today I ran into a situation where I have a column where I have this content `110&mode=tree`.

As I needed the `ID` only I said to myself... like usual, split and get the first value only:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM dbo._fnSplit('110&mode=tree','&')
```

As I needed the value as int I added a CAST() around it.

```
CAST((SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM dbo._fnSplit('110&mode=tree','&')) AS int)
```

Now after execution I got:

> *mode=tree cannot be converted to a type int*

Huch? I get only the first value which is an `Id` (I double checked the results) but it still try to convert the 2nd value as well. So it seems that SQL Server handles it differently in execution.

**Question:**

So is it generally possible to control how the execution plans handle this behaviour?

**Sidenote:**

I solved it for now doing this:

```
[...] WHERE id = CAST((CASE WHEN k.param LIKE '%&%' THEN LEFT(k.swindowparam,PATINDEX('%&%',k.param)-1) ELSE k.swindowparam END) AS int))
```

Check if string contains & and if so so a LEFT with length found out by `PATINDEX`.

EDIT:

Here is the split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_Split(@text nvarchar(4000), @delimiter char(1) = ',')

RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(
position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
value nvarchar(4000)
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

SET @text = RTRIM(LTRIM(@text))

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
BEGIN
SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)
IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
BREAK
END
IF (@index > 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
END
ELSE
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
END
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your split function is returning the data in an unspecified order.  To solve the problem I would change that function so it returns the results in the expect order every time.

Depending on how the function is implemented you may be able to correct this behavior by adding an ORDER BY statement.  SQL Server doesn't guarantee that a set will be returned in any specific order by default.

Comment: I added a ORDER BY already since my split function returns value and position column. So I sort by position ASC, but the error is still the same. That confuses me still.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the split function?

Comment: I added the function to the question.

Comment: Since the function is returning a table try ordering by the position:  SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM dbo.fn_Split('110&mode=tree','&') ORDER BY [position]

Comment: If you run "SELECT [value], [position] FROM dbo.fn_Split('110&mode=tree','&') ORDER BY [position]" you should be able to verify that position 1 is returned first, and its value is "110".  Then if you take the top 1 result it should only return position 1, value "110".  If this isn't the case then either the split function is different or there could be some language setting that is causing the ORDER statement to order differently than we expect.

Comment: What you wrote is exactly what I did, and as I said, that why I am confused about it, is that I get exactly the integer 110 as result, but if I cast the results it runs into an error as pointed out. So reviewed it is not a case I can't handle otherwise like I did, I was just confused about the way the execution plan seems to handle this.

Comment: I close this task and mark your answer, thx for your effort. As it was more a theoretically question I can live with it how it is.